# CreateParams when not on UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am trying to prevent the flickering when loading forms. I am loading a form through a new thread and then invoke back to UI. But since I am creating the form on the non UI thread, the override (CreateParams) is not working as intended. Works flawlessly when I create it on the UI thread. How can I make it that it overrides when its back on the UI thread?

```
// How the loading is done, from UI thread
Thread GetPage = new Thread(() => LoadPage<T>(panel));

public static void LoadPage<T>(Panel Panel)
{ 
  Form form = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) as Form;

  // Now invoke to UI
   Panel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
   {
       form.TopLevel = false;
       form.AutoScroll = true;
       Panel.Controls.Add(form);
       form.Show();
   }
}

// Example of a form

public partial class Start : Form
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams { get { CreateParams cp =     
             base.CreateParams; cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; return cp; } }

    public Start()
    {
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: So you only want to run the constructor on a separate thread and then migrate the form over to the UI thread?

Comment: @DanielBrückner , yes. Because sometimes the Form can be pretty slow at loading and I don't wanna freeze the UI.

Comment: This is a completely unsupported use case in WinForms. You cannot safely do this. Period. Determine what causes the form to load so slowly and push those parts into background threads. But anything that involves control creation must happen on the UI thread.

Comment: "since I am creating the form on the non UI thread" Wrong. You now have *two* UI threads. Window handles have thread affinity -- they belong to whichever thread they're created on. And while WinForms does allow you to have multiple UI threads, it's extremely unlikely to be what you actually want.

Answer (score 5):

It ought to be little obvious that it doesn't have anything to do with threading, considering that you are properly invoking to the UI thread.  The value that CreateParams returns does in fact only get used when the native window is created.  Which happens at the Controls.Add() call, which runs on the UI thread.  Nothing wrong with that aspect of the code.  And required, you'll crash the program if you try to set the parent of a window created on the wrong thread.

The real problem is the WS_EX_COMPOSITED style flag you are using.  Compositing is only supported for top-level windows.  The Form class in Winforms.  But you defeated it by setting the TopLevel property to *false*.  The style flag simply stops having an effect, there's no alternative for this for a client window.  You'll need to move it to the parent Form that contains this child window.

Comment: I'm not sure this is all correct. When I crack open the framework in reflector, I see that the default constructor of `Control` calls internal constructor `Control(bool)`. That second constructor has a call to `this.CreateParams` (violating the don't-call-a-virtual-from-a-constructor rule) that is invoked when `this.DefaultSize` returns any non-zero size part. Form overrides `DefaultSize` to set it to {300,300}, so `CreateParams` should be called on whatever thread the constructor runs on.

Comment: Also, `Control(bool)` has calls to things like `InitMouseWheelSupport` and ` WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.InstallIfNeeded` which have some very UI-thread-specific code in them.

Comment: That's irrelevant, Invoke() of course insists that this was already done.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do this. WinForms controls must be created on the thread on which they'll be used, and they must be used from the thread that created them (the only exceptions being `InvokeRequired`, `Invoke`, `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke`). Failure to follow these basic rules will result in failures.